# ImageView inside ScrollView with onTouch() or onClick() Event

Tags: android, android-imageview, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

I have an `ImageView` inside a `ScrollView`. The `ImageView` is clickable and opens up a new `Activity`.

Whenever I scroll through my ScrollView first touching the image (But not releasing my finger yet) and try to scroll it fires my `onTouch()` or `onClick()` method (I have tried with both...)

Here is my code:

```
btnAdd.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
           startActivity(intent);
           return true;
       }
});
```

As I said I also tried with `onClick()`...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the OnTouchListener is triggered it listen for multiple actions (Action Down, Action Up, etc) and executes them all so you should specify exactly when you want to start the new activity (in your case on Action Up). So try to use this:

```
 btnAdd.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```